# Trying to display Coefficients using knitr::kable

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, coefficients

I am using R markdown and am trying to use knitr to create a table for my coefficients from a glm but the table is formatting incorrectly.

#this is the code I input

```
coefficient <- coef(poissonglm)
knitr::kable(coefficient)
```

table it creates

|................................................................................ x |

| (Intercept)|...................................... 1.0044444 |

| Medium|0.2435355||High..........0.5232323 |

| Temp  |............................................ -0.0111111 |

Comment: Which result do you want to see?